# Dynamic Excel Subtraction

Tags: excel, dynamic, subtraction

Say I've got cells A1-A10 populated with numbers. My initial formula in cell B1 is =A1-A6. However, I'd like to strike-out cell A3 (keeping the contents visible underneath the strike-out if possible), and I'd like the formula in B1 to recognise that change, and then automatically adjust itself to =A1-A7 (the idea being that I'd like A1 subtracted by the number in the cell 5 "non-struck out" cells below it). And then if I strike out cell A5 I'd like the formula to adjust itself to =A1-A8 and so on. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

(**EDIT#1:** misread the input, sorry)

A bit straightforward, but will do the job: type `=A1-INDIRECT("A"&SMALL(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A),""),6))` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>ENTER</kbd> - this will define an ARRAY formula and will result in `{}` brackets around it (but do NOT type them manually!).

To speed up calculation you may replace A:A to any limited range.

Sample file (resulting formula is yellow-marked): https://www.dropbox.com/s/sy7zkg71xtfgib9/Subtract5th.xlsx

(**EDIT#2:** misread the "strike-out", sorry)

Font styles (as well as similar cell properties) may NOT be read by default Excel functions, that's why you need to add UDF called `StrikeOut`:

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> - thiss will open VBA editor.
2. Insert new module: `Insert > Module`.
3. Paste the code to added module:

   ```
   Function StrikeOut(R As Range) As Long
   Dim c As Range
   StrikeOut = 0
   For Each c In R.Cells
       If c.Font.Strikethrough = True Then StrikeOut = StrikeOut + 1
   Next
   End Function
   ```
4. Add the formula to B1: `=A1-INDIRECT("A"&(6+StrikeOut(A2:A10)))`
5. Set strikethrough font to any cells in `A1:A10`.
6. Unfortunately, cell format change does NOT trigger any change event, so you need either press <kbd>F9</kbd> or change any cell value on the sheet to recalculate and therefore update result in `B1`.

Sample file is shared: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n9o7tn3ks3x8nza/StrikeOut.xlsm

P.S. at least for me that was extremely useful)))

Comment: I tried this but can't get it to work. If I strike through a number the formula result does not update (incl. `F9` force recalc)

Comment: @Remnant it seems we have a misunderstanding due to my bad English: I understood "strike-out" as cleared or deleted, i.e. resulting cell is empty. What do you mean by strike out? the text is present but it crossed by a line?

Comment: I think strike-out is a number with a line through it. We will need the OP to clarify...

Comment: @PeterL.: +1 Nice solution! Only change I'd recommend: replace `INDIRECT("A"&(6+StrikeOut(A2:A10)))` with `INDEX($A:$A,5+StrikeOut(A2:A10))`! This will make it non-volatile, i.e. only run the UDF in case anything in A1:A10 changes - while with INDIRECT it'll always run when a recalc is done. Not that it really matters for 10 cells, but I guess its general good practice. PS: I also misread "strike-through"! ;-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert brilliant) I'd +1 that suggestion of yours! Definitely - as I said in P.S. above - I learned from this Q much more than asker, I suppose)))

Comment: Regarding the non-firing of the change event (that was new to me, too) - check out the workaround provided at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/3704-calculate-format-change.html - it's a bit of an effort and probably not worth to use here - but good to know it is possible! :-)